# Can old Jewish books be restored by non-Jewish experts?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, jewish-books

Can old Jewish books be restored by non-Jewish experts?
For example, i am non-Jews have old books related to Judaism.
But it is too old. So, there is a way to restore old books in the traditional Asian way.
If so, can I restore it that way?
not a sefer torah just simple judaism book

Comment: Do you mean fix the bindings? You can do that however you want.

Comment: @N.T. More than that, the torn paper is restored and various restoration work is done.

Comment: As long as the bookbinder doing the work understands which way the book is read and held you should be relatively OK.